# Why can't I interpolate the $cgi->param($key)?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am debugging this script and the value of the CGI params are showing up like this:

```
username
CGI=HASH(0x55887d94d850)->param{username} <--- Why is that? It should show the value.
password
CGI=HASH(0x55887d94d850)->param{password} <---
```

The value of the parameter should be printed instead I get this HASH thingy. Why is that?

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                                                                           
use strict;                                                                                                                  
use warnings;                                                                                                                
use CGI("-utf8");                                                                                                            
use CGI::Session;                                                                                                            
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
sub BEGIN {
  unshift (@INC, '/var/application/module/');
};                                                                                                                           
use Auth;

### Header                                                                                                                   
########################                                                                                                     
my $cgi = CGI->new();

##########                                                                                                                   
if ( $ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq "POST" ) {
  my %form;
  my $session_dir="/var/tmp";
  my ($admin_user,$admin_password) = ("admin","arun123");

  print "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
  print "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
  print "<html>\n";
  foreach my $key ($cgi->param()) {
    $form{$key} = $cgi->param($key);
    #print "<h3>$key $cgi->param{$key}</h3>\n";                                                                              
    print "<h3>$key</h3>\n";
    print "<h3>$cgi->param($key)</h3>\n";
  };
  print "</html>\n";
  exit;
```

When I use the Variable method then the result is correct:

```
password arun123
username admin

  my %vars = $cgi->Vars();
  my $args;
  for my $key (keys %vars) {
    my $var = $vars{$key};
    chomp $var;
    $var =~ s/^\s+//;
    $var =~ s/\s+$//;
    $args->{$key} = $var;
    print "<h3>$key $var</h3>\n";
  };
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print "<h3>$cgi->param{$key}</h3>\n";
```

interpolates variables `$cgi` and `$key` into a string but does not evaluate perl code.

Try

```
print "<h3>".$cgi->param($key)."</h3>\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

[@clamp already explained your particular output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76794634/2766176), but there's more to the story.

Perl interpolates some sequences in a double-quoted context ([perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata)).

- character numbers in various bases, such as `\012`, `\x0a`, `\x{23CE}`, and so on.
- pre-defined character escapes, such as `\n`.
- variable names starting with `$` or `@`, including subscripts for single element access in the case of `$` and slices in the case of `@`. Note that `%` slices aren't part of that.

In your case, you are trying to include the result of a method call. Perl doesn't interpolate those, which is why it iterpolates `$cgi` and `$key` as a two separate scalar variables.

There are some ways around this. First, consider `sprintf` or `printf`, which I find nicer for complicated

```
printf "<h3>%s</h3>\n", $cgi->param($key);
```

Second, as @clamp noted,

```
print "<h3>" . $cgi->param($key) . "</h3>\n";
```

Third, since you can dereference an array to interpolate its contents, and Perl allows you to put an anonymous array constructor inside the braces:

```
print "<h3>@{[$cgi->param($key)]}</h3>\n";
```

And last, you can use various templating systems instead. This way you don't have your HTML scattered throughout your program.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you did the assignment correctly

```
    $form{$key} = $cgi->param($key);
```

, calling $cgi->param as a function with argument $key, but your print

```
    print "<h3>$cgi->param{$key}</h3>\n";
```

appears to be treating $cgi-param as a hash - perhaps

```
    print "<h3>$cgi->param($key)</h3>\n";
```

is what you're after?

Comment: print "<h3>$cgi->param($key)</h3>\n"; yields CGI=HASH(0x558aa6e62850)->param(username)

Comment: You can't interpolate method calls. See my own answer.